# "Syntax error, unrecognized expression" error whilst using jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [Googled this exception](http://google.com/search?q=Syntax+error,+unrecognized+expression), and it seems to mostly boil down to people using the old `option[@select]` style attribute selector.

My problem, however, is a little different. When I get the error, there is no line number being attributed to it.

I think it has something to do with the hashes I am using for my page.

I have tried a lot of `console.log()`, etc, but haven't been able to figure it out. This is happening in Firefox and Safari.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
$(window.location.hash).find('.info').css({ display: 'block' });
```

The `$(window.location.hash)` means you would be looking for an element in the page with the hash as a selector.

You probably meant to do:

```
$(window.location.hash.replace('!/', '')).find('.info').css({ display: 'block' });
```

Comment: How the hell did I not find that??? +1 and AA when I can :) I fixed it by putting in a condition for that code.